# Formal way to describe protocols

Tags: protocols, specifications, formal-methods

Is there a formal/traditional way to describe data/command exchange protocols? For example, for programming languages there are multiple approaches to describe the syntax and semantics (like: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form).

The approach I am looking for is rather utilitarian (in contrast to academic). I need something for day-to-day use for data exchange description while working on specifications, just to transfer/spread clearly the idea to others. So, if there is something that is not recognized as a de-facto standard but is useful - it is ok too.

I took a look at UML sequence diagrams and "Formal Methods for Communication Protocol Specification And Verification, by Carl A. Sunshine, 1979". Former method is missing the description of "payloads" (at least from what I understood) while latter one is rather an educative paper describing considerations rather than methods (I am still going through this paper, though).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protocols are about messages sent in accordance to a series of interactions.

The best way to specify protocols that I have seen is with [Colored Petri Nets (CPNs)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coloured_Petri_net).

CPNs are based on ("uncolored") [Petri Nets (PNs)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petri_net), which define how parallel activities synchronize, e.g., the message responses, by using Places to represent possible states, Tokens-in-places to represent state, and transition (synchronization) gates to indicate where parallel states must coincide to make progress.  Petri Nets can model Finite State Machines (an FSA is a PN that always has a "single token", e.g., the "current state") and so are a generalization; in fact, they can "exponentially compress" certain FSAs into very small descriptions and can thus be quite succinct even for complex interaction sequences.  But a conventional PN does not address the data being exchanged.

CPNs generalize PNs to add data types. The tokens now have "colors" (funny way to say "data type") and transitions can not only synchronize but can combine tokens to produce other tokens, e.g., compute new values.

A protocol modelled as CPN thus has message content as data types, and PNs states to indicate the syncronization.   If you've never used a CPN, it is really worth your trouble to learn what they are, because they are such a pretty generalization of FSAs.

Regarding OPs' "utilitarian" remark, there are very good tools available at [CPN Tools](http://cpntools.org/), including graphical modelling and code generation.

Answer (score 1):

In telecommunications, the standard for describing interaction between network elements is [Z.100 : Specification and Description Language (SDL)](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-Z.100) and the companion [Z.120 : Message Sequence Chart (MSC)](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-Z.120) recommendations. The suite includes a testing framework.

A more mathematically bent approach would be to use various state machine models of some type.

One of the early publications, [Design and Validation of Computer Protocols](http://spinroot.com/gerard/popd.html) (1991), was written by Gerard Holzmann to describe the SPIN model checker and the PROMELA language.

Almost any other notation like TLA+, Petri-nets, Alloy, CSP, Z, ... can also be used to reason about protocols and the choice often depends on familiarity and tools availability.

If rigour is not essential, then [Harel state charts](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~harel/papers/Statecharts.History.pdf) provide a notation familiar to many engineers.

Fundamentally, the problem with sequence charts on their own is that they describe a single trace through the protocol. They cannot easily show the non-determinism required to describe parallel operations, and struggle to succinctly represent choice. When extended with hierarchical message charts (HMC) then they fall back into the state machine space.

Answer (score 1):

If by "utilitarian" you mean "useful", consider Petri Nets. Please see my reply below or consider a [PDF version](http://www.aespen.ca/AEnswers/lMtbX1428143440.pdf) of the reply.

[first page of reply http://www.aespen.ca/AEnswers/lMtbX1428143440-0_Page_1.jpg](http://www.aespen.ca/AEnswers/lMtbX1428143440-0_Page_1.jpg)
[second page of reply http://www.aespen.ca/AEnswers/lMtbX1428143440-0_Page_2.jpg](http://www.aespen.ca/AEnswers/lMtbX1428143440-0_Page_2.jpg)

Comment: You should agree that in this form it is hard to describe every value to be transferred and every bit to be checked.

But for presenting the protocol it could be usefu, I do agree. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I have not tried to describe a protocol to the bit level. I do agree that it appears as if it would be challenging to describe this level in terms of Petri Nets. It would be interesting to see the types of challenges one would encounter in these descriptions and if there are systematic methods to mitigate the descriptions in ways that map clearly to Petri Net elements.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand your comment (where you are asking if the types of challenges are systematic). Please elaborate with examples. The challenge I see is that with this notation the description will be too bulky. Plain text form with left and right side columns (representing receiver and transmitter) will be less formal but more applicable, I assume.

Comment: Here is an image of my reply (with more details and examples) to your comment. [image](http://www.aespen.ca/AEnswers/WjTpY1429533268.jpg). A PDF version of the reply is also available, figures will be dynamic. [link](http://www.aespen.ca/AEnswers/WjTpY1429533268.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, since you mention BNF:  I believe I have read that Wirth used EBNF to specify protocols, with prose explaining which parts of the string were to be emitted by the client and which parts by the server.  I am unable to find the reference off-hand, but my recollection is that the example I read was clearer than most protocol descriptions I have read elsewhere.

Comment: BNF is a lousy way to model protocols.  It doesn't model state worth a damn.  (You might be able to define strings going back and forth, but most BNF is context-free which means "not much memory of the past (left context)".   It might be used model message structure.  But you likely want a more complex model involving constraints; check out XML Schemas as a more sophisticated data modelling tool that is a superset of BNF.

Comment: I doubt that Wirth limited the definition of the protocol to what can be captured by EBNF, any more than he banned declaration-before-use rules and type declarations from his programming languages.  But ... point well taken.  (And I'll be sure to look at XSD sometime ... :-)